# How to align XWPFTable cells on the decimal

Tags: apache-poi, text-alignment, xwpf

I am creating a table using Apache POI XWPF, and I need to align decimal values on the decimal point. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: How would you do this in `Word`? Using a decimal tabstop?

Comment: Yes. I didn't even think of using a tabstop or how I would normally do it. Looking through the documentation of tabstop, they have a decimal choice. Thank you.